# Hamburger menu css cursor

Tags: html, css, cursor, hamburger-menu

I was playing around with hamburger menu using CSS only.  One thing that I encounter is the cursor pointer.  When I hover the cursor over the hamburger button, it wouldn't change to pointer if it was between white lines.  It only works when it hover on white lines.  I tried figuring it out how to solve this issue but no luck so far.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
.nav-trigger {
    cursor: pointer;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is the link to my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/dxs6040/51wdfypj/2/

Comment: One solution would be to wrap your `input` and `label` in a DIV that itself had the `cursor:pointer` style applied.  Seems like something you'd have wrapped for easier positioning anyway.

Comment: I tried that and now it seems the pointer work when hovering all over the hamburger menu except for clicking.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your `<input>` and `<label>` tags inside a `<div>` that has `cursor:pointer;` set on your CSS.

```
<div id="menu">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger"/>
  <label id="menuButton" for="nav-trigger"></label>
</div>
```

In your CSS file, add:

```
#menu {
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 15px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 35px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

If you want to make further changes, simply adjust the `#menu`'s properties at will.

**Working result:** https://jsfiddle.net/emur3bgf/

Comment: The pointer now works, however when I click it between the white lines, it doesn't trigger at all.  Any idea why this may happen?

Comment: This is because state changes are linked to nav-trigger, not #menu. You would have to update that in the CSS (move the actions from nav-trigger to the menu div we just created)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your label with a div and set styles like below;

```
position: fixed;
top: 5px;
right: 15px;
height: 25px;
width: 35px;
cursor: pointer;
```